# Angular 5 application freezes when opened in multiple tabs - chrome

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular6, angular-permission

We have built our application using angular 5. Application performance is good but with the below scenario, the application gets hung.

opening the application in one tab and duplicating the browser tab, will freeze the angular application running in the first tab until the angular application in the second tab is completely loaded.

The application have service calls and also we are using a browser cookie (JWT stored as cookie)

what may be the reason?

Comment: Any error in the console after it?

Comment: no error, but even the button click will not work until the application loads on the other tab.

Comment: Have you checked the behavior In all other browsers?

Comment: Please check any statement running in loop and better don't call service calls from ngOnChanges if anything implemented

Answer (score 0):

In my app I had this problem due to making a connection to a SignalR backed on application start.